# Stop the audio player

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an audio script with play/pause, I want to make the audio stop when I click on the square button at the left, and to add the timing to the right

here is the code: https://codepen.io/Amirafik/pen/YzxQZQw

HTML

```
<div class="title">
  Dina Mohamed
</div>
<div class="stop"></div>
<div id="audioButton">
  <div id="playerContainer">
    <div class="listen">LISTEN</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="duration">
  00:12
</div>
<br>_____________________________________________________</br>
<div class="note">
  <p>All items were more than perfect, we loved the experience and will order ONE OAK services again in the future for sure. <!--<span style="color:#F04E36"><br> Dina sent us an amazing feedback about her experience, tap the play button to listen to her cheerful words.</span></p>-->
</div
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=montserrat:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900');

body {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 16px ;
  font-family: "montserrat" ;
  font-weight: 500;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
a {
  color: #F04E36;
}
.title {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight:700;
  display:inline-block;
}
.note {
  max-width: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #000000;
  display:inline-block;
}
.circle-audio-player {
  cursor: pointer;
  width:25px;
  padding:0px;
  margin-top:-67%;
  margin-bottom:-50%;
  margin-left:-7px;
  background-color:#EDEBE7;
  border-radius:50%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#playerContainer {
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#audioButton {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px; 
  max-width: 85px;
  height: 10px;  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-left:2px;
}
.listen {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight:700;
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-top:-5%;
  font-size: 14px ;
}
.stop {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left:10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-weight:500;
  font-size: 14px ;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.duration {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight:500;
  font-size: 14px ;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

JS

```
// settings
var DEFAULTS = {
    borderColor: "#EDEBE7",
    playedColor: "#F04E36",
    backgroundColor: "#d3cdc2",
    iconColor: "#000000",
    borderWidth: 2,
    size: 48,
    className: 'circle-audio-player'
  
};

// reused values
var pi = Math.PI;
var doublePi = pi * 2;
var arcOffset = -pi / 2;
var animTime = 200;
var loaderTime = 1800;

var CircleAudioPlayer = function (options) {
    options = options || {};
    for (var property in DEFAULTS) {
        this[property] = options[property] || DEFAULTS[property];
    }

    // create some things we need
    this._canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this._canvas.setAttribute('class', this.className + ' is-loading');
    this._canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (function () {
        if (this.playing) {
            this.pause();
        }
        else {
            this.play();
        }
    }).bind(this));
    this._ctx = this._canvas.getContext('2d');

    // set up initial stuff
    this.setAudio(options.audio);
    this.setSize(this.size);

    // redraw loop
    (function cAPAnimationLoop (now) {
        // check if we need to update anything
        if (this.animating) {
            this._updateAnimations(now);
        }
        if (this._forceDraw || this.playing || this.animating || this.loading) {
            this._draw();
            this._forceDraw = false;
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(cAPAnimationLoop.bind(this));
    }).call(this, new Date().getTime());
};
CircleAudioPlayer.prototype = {
    // private methods
    _animateIcon: function (to, from) {
        // define a few things the first time
        this._animationProps = {
            animStart: null,
            from: from,
            to: to
        };
        if (from) {
            this.animating = true;
        }
        else {
            this._animationProps.current = this._icons[to].slice();
            this.draw();
        }
    },
    _updateAnimations: function (now) {
        this._animationProps.animStart = this._animationProps.animStart || now;
        var deltaTime = now - this._animationProps.animStart;
        var perc = (1 - Math.cos(deltaTime / animTime * pi / 2));
        if (deltaTime >= animTime) {
            this.animating = false;
            perc = 1;
            this._animationProps.current = this._icons[this._animationProps.to].slice();
            this.draw();
        }
        else {
            var from = this._icons[this._animationProps.from];
            var current = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
                current.push([]);
                for (var j = 0; j < from[i].length; j++) {
                    current[i].push([]);
                    var to = this._icons[this._animationProps.to][i][j];
                    current[i][j][0] = from[i][j][0] + (to[0] - from[i][j][0]) * perc;
                    current[i][j][1] = from[i][j][1] + (to[1] - from[i][j][1]) * perc;
                }
            }
            this._animationProps.current = current;
        }
    },
    _draw: function (progress) {
        // common settings
        if (isNaN(progress)) {
            progress = this.audio.currentTime / this.audio.duration || 0;
        }

        // clear existing
        this._ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.size, this.size);

        // draw bg
        this._ctx.beginPath();
        this._ctx.arc(this._halfSize, this._halfSize, this._halfSize - (this.borderWidth / 2), 0, doublePi);
        this._ctx.closePath();
        this._ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;
        this._ctx.fill();

        // draw border
        // our active path is already the full circle, so just stroke it
        this._ctx.lineWidth = this.borderWidth;
        this._ctx.strokeStyle = this.borderColor;
        this._ctx.stroke();

        // play progress
        if (progress > 0) {
            this._ctx.beginPath();
            this._ctx.arc(this._halfSize, this._halfSize, this._halfSize - (this.borderWidth / 2), arcOffset, arcOffset + doublePi * progress);
            this._ctx.strokeStyle = this.playedColor;
            this._ctx.stroke();
        }

        // icons
        this._ctx.fillStyle = this.iconColor;
        if (this.loading) {
            var loaderOffset = -Math.cos((new Date().getTime() % (loaderTime)) / (loaderTime) * pi) * doublePi - (pi / 3) - (pi / 2);
            this._ctx.beginPath();
            this._ctx.arc(this._halfSize, this._halfSize, this._halfSize / 3, loaderOffset, loaderOffset + pi / 3 * 2);
            this._ctx.strokeStyle = this.iconColor;
            this._ctx.stroke();
        }
        else {
            this._ctx.beginPath();
            var icon = (this._animationProps && this._animationProps.current) || this._icons.play;
            for (var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
                this._ctx.moveTo(icon[i][0][0], icon[i][0][1]);

                for (var j = 1; j < icon[i].length; j++) {
                    this._ctx.lineTo(icon[i][j][0], icon[i][j][1]);
                }
            }

            // this._ctx.closePath();
            this._ctx.fill();
            // stroke to fill in for retina
            this._ctx.strokeStyle = this.iconColor;
            this._ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            this._ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
            this._ctx.stroke();
        }
    },
    _setState: function (state) {
        this.playing = false;
        this.loading = false;
        if (state === 'playing') {
            this.playing = true;
            this._animateIcon('pause', 'play');
        }
        else if (state === 'loading') {
            this.loading = true;
        }
        else if (this.state !== 'loading') {
            this._animateIcon('play', 'pause');
        }
        else {
            this._animateIcon('play', null);
        }
        this.state = state;
        this._canvas.setAttribute('class', this.className + ' is-' + state);
        this.draw();
    },
    // public methods
    draw: function () {
        this._forceDraw = true;
    },
    setSize: function (size) {
        this.size = size;
        this._halfSize = size / 2; // we do this a lot. it's not heavy, but why repeat?
        this._canvas.width = size;
        this._canvas.height = size;
        // set icon paths
        var iconSize = this.size / 2;
        var pauseGap = iconSize / 10;
        var playLeft = Math.cos(pi / 3 * 2) * (iconSize / 2) + this._halfSize;
        var playRight = iconSize / 2 + this._halfSize;
        var playHalf = (playRight - playLeft) / 2 + playLeft;
        var top = this._halfSize - Math.sin(pi / 3 * 2) * (iconSize / 2);
        var bottom = this.size - top;
        var pauseLeft = this._halfSize - iconSize / 3;
        var pauseRight = this.size - pauseLeft;
        this._icons = {
            play: [
                [
                    [playLeft, top],
                    [playHalf, (this._halfSize - top) / 2 + top],
                    [playHalf, (this._halfSize - top) / 2 + this._halfSize],
                    [playLeft, bottom]
                ],
                [
                    [playHalf, (this._halfSize - top) / 2 + top],
                    [playRight, this._halfSize],
                    [playRight, this._halfSize],
                    [playHalf, (this._halfSize - top) / 2 + this._halfSize]
                ]
            ],
            pause: [
                [
                    [pauseLeft, top + pauseGap],
                    [this._halfSize - pauseGap, top + pauseGap],
                    [this._halfSize - pauseGap, bottom - pauseGap],
                    [pauseLeft, bottom - pauseGap]
                ],
                [
                    [this._halfSize + pauseGap, top + pauseGap],
                    [pauseRight, top + pauseGap],
                    [pauseRight, bottom - pauseGap],
                    [this._halfSize + pauseGap, bottom - pauseGap]
                ]
            ]
        };

        if (this._animationProps && this._animationProps.current) {
            this._animateIcon(this._animationProps.to);
        }
        if (!this.playing) {
            this.draw();
        }
    },
    setAudio: function (audioUrl) {
        this.audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
        this._setState('loading');

        this.audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', (function () {
            this._setState('paused');
        }).bind(this));
        this.audio.addEventListener('play', (function () {
            this._setState('playing');
        }).bind(this));
        this.audio.addEventListener('pause', (function () {
            // reset when finished
            if (this.audio.currentTime === this.audio.duration) {
                this.audio.currentTime = 0;
            }
            this._setState('paused');
        }).bind(this));
    },
    appendTo: function (element) {
        element.appendChild(this._canvas);
    },
    play: function () {
        this.audio.play();
    },
    pause: function () {
        this.audio.pause();
    }
};


// now init one as an example
var cap = new CircleAudioPlayer({
    audio: 'https://www.siriusxm.com/content/dam/sxm-com/audio/test/audio-previews/audio_test03.mp3.png',
  size: 120,
  borderWidth: 8
});
cap.appendTo(playerContainer);
```

Comment: It don't seems like a good question to be asked by you , as you written a nice code written in CodePen . But to stop audio use `audio.pause()`. And share the minimum code here to reproduce the problem

Comment: Thank you, i need to stop it  then we can start the audion from the beginig... not to pause it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `AudioElement.pause()` to pause an running element, and the next `AudioElement.play()` will start from where you left off.
You can essentially set the `currentTime` property of the audio element to start from the beginning

A simple demonstration of how it works

```js
const pause = document.getElementById('pause');
const stop = document.getElementById('stop');
const play = document.getElementById('play');
const container = document.getElementById('player');
const duration = document.getElementById('duration');
const audio = new Audio('https://www.siriusxm.com/content/dam/sxm-com/audio/test/audio-previews/audio_test03.mp3.png');
let played = 0;
let playing = true;

const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
run = async function () {
    while(playing) {
        if (played == Math.floor(audio.duration)) break;
        duration.innerText = `${played} / ${Math.floor(audio.duration)}`;
        played++;
        await wait(1000);
    }
}
container.appendChild(audio);
stop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    duration.innerText = `0 / ${Math.floor(audio.duration)}`
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    played = 0;
    playing = false;
});

pause.addEventListener('click', () => {
    audio.pause();
    playing = false;
});

play.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playing = true
    audio.play();
    run();
});
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="duration">0.0</div>
<button id="play">play</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="pause">pause</button>
```